# How to DI router to get access to documentation()

Tags: playframework

A Play router has a `documentation` method that I'd like to access in a controller to provide (you guessed it!) documentation.

I used to get access to it via `play.api.Play.routes.documentation`, but of course `play.api.Play` is now deprecated.

So I've tried injecting the router into my controller:

```
@Singleton
class IndexCtrl @Inject()(implicit
                          components: ControllerComponents,
                          sil: Silhouette[OatEnv],
                          router: Router,
                          val ex: ExecutionContext
                         )
```

But that results in a circular dependency in Guice:

```
[info] oat.wsvc.controllers.IndexCtrlSpec *** ABORTED ***
[info]   com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[info] 
[info] 1) Found a circular dependency involving play.api.routing.Router, and circular dependencies are disabled.
[info]   while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
[info]   while locating play.api.routing.Router
[info]   at oat.wsvc.controllers.IndexCtrl.<init>(IndexCtrl.scala:29)
[info]   at oat.wsvc.controllers.IndexCtrl.class(IndexCtrl.scala:25)
[info]   while locating oat.wsvc.controllers.IndexCtrl
[info]     for the 18th parameter of wsvc.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:108)
[info]   while locating wsvc.Routes
[info]   while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
[info]   while locating play.api.routing.Router
[info]     for the 1st parameter of play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:222)
```

I've tried injecting the `RoutesProvider` mentioned in the error message; same result.  I tried injecting a router as a field in the class; same result.  I've noted and tried the section in the DI documentation on [managing circular dependencies](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Managing-circular-dependencies); same result.

How do I get access to the router using DI?

PS:  Note that this is different than getting access to the controller's routes.  The method I need is in the router itself.

Comment: Just wondering here about the use case. Do you want to get redirected to a route; or do you want to parse a page for some value? Overall what is the body of the action method that is using this injection (assuming the injection works).

Comment: @DaveRose:  The router has a method named "documentation" that produces three strings for every route in the router: the http method (GET, PUT), the path pattern, and the method that's invoked.  I use that to produce a page of rudimentary documentation on available api end-points.  In the longer term I'd like a better approach to producing documentation of the api, but for now this is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I faced was Guice errors when trying to inject a Router into a controller.  I can, however, inject a Router object into another class that doesn't have methods referenced by the router.

In my case I could rearrange my code to make use of the router's documentation when the application starts up.  So I injected it into a an eager singleton rather than a controller.